# Golang bubbletea delegate update messages to children

Tags: go, terminal

I am using the bubbletea Go package to create a TUI.

I have a parent model that has an array of children. These each initiate a command which run parallel for all children. When the child commands complete, the message is passed to the parent Update method, where it is passed back down to all the children in order to update them.
However, I only want to pass the message to the child component which created it.
How can I go about this in a scaleable way?

This is in the parent "Update" method. I only want to call Update on the child component that triggered the msg
[image]